# TensorFlow - "TypeError: Fetch Argument None"

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, typeerror, gradient-descent

TensorFlow is throwing a *TypeError* when I execute the simplest possible graph.

```
sess = tf.Session()
x1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
x2 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
z = x1

sess.run(tf.gradients(z, [x1, x2]), feed_dict={x1: 1, x2: 1})
```

This yields

```
TypeError: Fetch argument None has invalid type <class 'NoneType'>
```

*Interestingly, if I change one line of code to:*

```
z = x1 + x2
```

**Then everything works perfectly!**
Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2):

According to your description, I properly modify the code.

```
import tensorflow as tf

sess = tf.Session()
x1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
x2 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

z = x1
print sess.run(tf.gradients(z, [x1]), feed_dict={x1: 1})

z = x1 + x2
print sess.run(tf.gradients(z, [x1, x2]), feed_dict={x1: 1, x2: 1})
```

Now there is no error. I believe you can understand your problem.

When you are going to apply a function, you may need to look at the document. Here is the document on [`tf.gradients`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gradients).